# Knex migration don't create the tables

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, migration, knex.js

Lately I've been trying to use knexjs with docker and I run into weird errors. When I run knex migrate:latest within the container using the command: docker exec service sh -c "knex migrate:latest"; everything works fine but the tables are not actually created in the database.

My migration:

```
exports.up = knex => {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.createTable('users', table => { 
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('name').notNullable();
      table.string('username').unique().notNullable();
      table.string('email').unique().notNullable();
      table.string('password').notNullable();
      table.datetime('created_at').notNullable();
    }),
    knex.schema.createTable('user_settings',  table => {
      table.integer('user_id');
      table.integer('xp');
    }),
  ])
}

exports.down =  knex => {
  return Promise.all([
    knex.schema.dropTable('users'),
    knex.schema.dropTable('user_settings'),
  ])
}
```

my Knexfile

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'pg',
  debug:true,
  connection: {
    host:'postgres',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    port: '',
    database: 'users'
  },
  migrations: {
    tableName: 'knex_migrations'
  }
};
```

my docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/app
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  users:
    container_name: users-service
    restart: always
    build: ./users
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./users:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

I can see that the sequences knex_migrations_id_seq, knex_migrations_lock_index_seq and users_id_seq have been created.

Answer (score 0):

Knex won't create the sequences without creating the tables. I've tried your migration with a local test setup I use for Stack Overflow questions, and it works fine (the stack uses `docker-compose`, though the config is trivially different to yours).

There could be a variety of reasons why the tables appear to be absent, depending on what you're using to look for them. The simplest way to go is probably to connect to your database using:

```
psql postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/users
```

and then issue a `\dt` command. If you don't see the table listed, you could try `\dn+` to show the available schemas and permissions for each. Specifically asking for the table via `\d users` (or even `\d public.users`) may be helpful.

If you still can't "see" the tables, perhaps edit your question with more detail about how you're testing for them, and someone may be able to help further.

Here's a simple `docker-compose.yml` you could try your migration against:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_DB: users
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

You can use the adminer web interface on http://localhost:8080 to browse the database if psql is not your preferred tool.

Comment: I still can't see the tables, would love to see the config you're using! Also what informations can I add that would be useful for this purpose?

Comment: Well, perhaps the output of the migration (suggest adding a `.debug()` for more detail) and more information on how you're checking to see if the tables exist. I'll add a sample `docker-compose.yml`.